# Youtube PHP library with OAuth 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, oauth-2.0, gdata

According to the [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub), the AuthSub method is officially deprecated in place of OAuth 2.0.  The problem is, their PHP library v2 is built using Zend Gdata, which from what I can tell, doesn't work well with OAuth.  On the other hand, [v3 of their API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) is not only still in development, but it looks like it doesn't support YouTube calls quite yet.

So my question is, what's the best way to make API calls using v2 of the library after authenticating using OAuth2?  Am I best just using AuthSub until a new library comes out?

Comment: Python is in a similar place right now, with the official SDK not supporting oAuth2 and using the old AuthSub method.  This method does not allow one to remove tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call the Youtube api with the the v3 php library. You can find code samples [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php).